# Parse XML with namespaces in TSQL - children details

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have xml like below, I have managed to get one of the variables of physicalAddress at a time, but I want to get all of the existing records in the child note if exists, otherwise I am having duplicate issues.

Desired outcome would be to get all children records in a column against each record details, so if 5 addresses, I would have 5 records with address part different in each row

I appreciate your help.

Thank you

XML used:

```
 `<PostData xmlns="mypath">
 <data>
     <Studentebo:CurrentEBO xmlns:Studentebo="MMMMMMM">
     <Studentebo:Person>       
        <ns6:PersonName xmlns:ns6="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ" xmlns="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ">
           <ns6:FirstName>Example3</ns6:FirstName>
           <ns6:MiddleName>Example3</ns6:MiddleName>
           <ns6:LastName>Example4</ns6:LastName>
           <ns6:PreferredName>testTest4</ns6:PreferredName>
           <ns6:Title>MRS.</ns6:Title>
        </ns6:PersonName>        
        <ns6:PhysicalAddresses xmlns:ns6="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ" 
            xmlns="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ">
           <ns6:PhysicalAddress>
              <ns15:Identification xmlns:ns15="OOOOO" xmlns="OOOOO">
                 <ns15:AddressNumber>125a6407-1b91-4d2c-a783- 
                 280127f38249</ns15:AddressNumber>
              </ns15:Identification>
              <ns15:AddressUsages xmlns:ns15="XXXXXXX" xmlns="XXXXXXX">
                 <ns15:AddressUsage>
                    <ns9:UsageCode xmlns:ns9="QQQQQ" 
                          xmlns="QQQQQ">HOME</ns9:UsageCode>
                 </ns15:AddressUsage>
              </ns15:AddressUsages>
              <ns15:EffectiveDates xmlns:ns15="XXXXXXX" xmlns="XXXXXXX">
                 <ns12:StartDateTime xmlns:ns12="LLLLLL" 
                         xmlns="LLLLLL">2018-01- 
                      07T00:00:00+00:00</ns12:StartDateTime>
                 <ns12:EndDateTime xmlns:ns12="LLLLLL" xmlns="LLLLLL">2064- 
                01-03T00:00:00+00:00</ns12:EndDateTime>
              </ns15:EffectiveDates>
              <Address1 xmlns:ns12="XXXXXXX" xmlns="XXXXXXX">Testing Address 
                        line2</Address1>
              <Address2 xmlns:ns12="XXXXXXX" xmlns="XXXXXXX">test4 
                    line2</Address2>
              <Address3 xmlns:ns12="XXXXXXX" x 
                       mlns="XXXXXXX">line33</Address3>
              <City xmlns:ns12="XXXXXXX" xmlns="XXXXXXX">Testing</City>
              <PostalCode xmlns:ns12="XXXXXXX" 
                xmlns="XXXXXXX">Testing</PostalCode>
              <Country xmlns:ns12="XXXXXXX" 
                         xmlns="XXXXXXX">Testing</Country>
           </ns6:PhysicalAddress>
           <ns6:PhysicalAddress>
              <ns15:Identification xmlns:ns15="OOOOO" xmlns="OOOOO">
                 <ns15:AddressNumber>125a6407-1b91-4d2c-a783- 
                 280127f38249</ns15:AddressNumber>
              </ns15:Identification>
              <ns15:AddressUsages xmlns:ns15="XXXXXXX" xmlns="XXXXXXX">
                 <ns15:AddressUsage>
                    <ns9:UsageCode xmlns:ns9="QQQQQ" 
                 xmlns="QQQQQ">HOME</ns9:UsageCode>
                 </ns15:AddressUsage>
              </ns15:AddressUsages>
              <ns15:EffectiveDates xmlns:ns15="XXXXXXX" xmlns="XXXXXXX">
                 <ns12:StartDateTime xmlns:ns12="LLLLLL" 
                     xmlns="LLLLLL">2018-01- 
                         07T00:00:00+00:00</ns12:StartDateTime>
                 <ns12:EndDateTime xmlns:ns12="LLLLLL" xmlns="LLLLLL">2064- 
       01-03T00:00:00+00:00</ns12:EndDateTime>
              </ns15:EffectiveDates>
              <Address1 xmlns:ns12="XXXXXXX" xmlns="XXXXXXX">Testing Address 
            line2</Address1>
              <Address2 xmlns:ns12="XXXXXXX" xmlns="XXXXXXX">test4 
             line2</Address2>
              <Address3 xmlns:ns12="XXXXXXX" 
                  xmlns="XXXXXXX">line33</Address3>
              <City xmlns:ns12="XXXXXXX" xmlns="XXXXXXX">Testing</City>
              <PostalCode xmlns:ns12="XXXXXXX" 
                  xmlns="XXXXXXX">Testing</PostalCode>
              <Country xmlns:ns12="XXXXXXX" 
                     xmlns="XXXXXXX">Testing</Country>
           </ns6:PhysicalAddress>
        </ns6:PhysicalAddresses>            
           </Studentebo:Person>
      <Studentebo:CurrentEBO>
```

SELECT used:

```
SELECT id, t.r.value('
                 declare namespace C1="mypath";
                 declare namespace CAM1="MMMMMMM";
                 declare namespace C2="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
                 declare namespace CAM2="OOOOO";
                       (.)', 'varchar(50)') as address1
FROM
[XXX_SH_SOAService_formattedXML] OUTER APPLY
[XML].nodes('
                 declare namespace C1="mypath";
                 declare namespace CAM1="MMMMMMM";
                 declare namespace C2="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
                 declare namespace CAM2="OOOOO";

 /C1:PostData/C1:data/CAM1:CurrentEBO/ 
 CAM1:Person/C2:PhysicalAddresses/C2:PhysicalAddress/CAM2:Address1') t(r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the construction of this XML is under your countrol you should try to change this mess of namespaces... It's especially difficult to see in which ns an element is living with over and over newly defined **default namespaces**.

In most cases it is best to be *as specific as possible*. But here I'd suggest to ignore the namespaces by using a wildcard everywhere:

```
SELECT t.ID 
      ,pers.value(N'(*:PersonName/*:FirstName/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(200)') AS Person_FirstName
      --more of Person
      ,addr.value(N'(*:Identification/*:AddressNumber/text())[1]',N'uniqueidentifier') AS Address_Number
      --AddressUsage would need one more `.nodes()`, as it is 1:n within each address
      ,addr.value(N'(*:EffectiveDates/*:StartDateTime/text())[1]',N'datetime2') AS Address_StartDateTime
      ,addr.value(N'(*:Address1/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Address_Address1
      ,addr.value(N'(*:Address2/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Address_Address2
      ,addr.value(N'(*:Address3/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Address_Address3
      ,addr.value(N'(*:City/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Address_City
      --more of the same
FROM @tbl AS t
OUTER APPLY t.YourXml.nodes(N'/*:PostData/*:data/*:CurrentEBO/*:Person') A(pers)
OUTER APPLY pers.nodes(N'*:PhysicalAddresses/*:PhysicalAddress') B(addr);
```

I do not under stand this:

> I would have 5 records with address part different in each row

But the above should point you the way...

Comment: Although I did it in another way, I just used [XML].query() to separate the children and then got there values. using [XML].value() then left join with common fields. But thank you for your help, this is a lot simpler to work with. I'm new to querying XML into TSQL and been looking around so much, I know the namespaces did my heading, they are everywhere :( marked your respond as the answer.